# 404 error in starting solr

Tags: java, solr, jetty

I've followed the advice on installing and starting up solr, but seems to be hitting a brickwall now. After downloading solr, here's what I've done

```
tar -zxvf apache-solr-3.4.0.tgz
cd apache-solr-3.4.0

cd example
java -jar start.jar
```

After this when I navigate to

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/
```

I get a 404 with Reason :

I checked out this solution on stackoverflow 
https://serverfault.com/questions/312213/why-is-solr-admin-panel-not-showing

But even this doesn't seem to work. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using the ancient Solr 3.4? The admin UI was completely re-engineered for Solr 4 and the latest version available is 4.10.2. I suggest you use the latest if you are just starting out.

Comment: I'm now trying the latest version with the same problem.

Comment: Just try localhost:8983. It should redirect you to the right path.